# Why is there a HTTP status message when there already is a HTTP status code?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

An HTTP response may look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I think `200` is already tell client that it is OK, and `OK` in response can be omitted.  So what is the approach that is existed?

Comment: Because humans understand "Not Found" better than "404".

Comment: @tkausl I think nobody read HTTP directly, browser or some tool s can translate this for us. If we omit this, it can reduce http's message size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#rfc.section.3.1.2:

> The reason-phrase element exists for the sole purpose of providing a textual description associated with the numeric status code, mostly out of deference to earlier Internet application protocols that were more frequently used with interactive text clients. A client SHOULD ignore the reason-phrase content.

Answer (score 1):

Such message is called **reason phrase** and, as mentioned in [Julian Reschke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55677981/1426227), it simply provides a textual description associated with the numeric status code and it should be ignored by the client. The reason phrase can even be empty.

While your question is about the HTTP/1.1 protocol, I would like to highlight that HTTP/2 responses don't carry any reason phrase. They carry only the status code, as defined in the [RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540):

> For HTTP/2 responses, a single `:status` pseudo-header field is defined that carries the HTTP status code field. This pseudo-header field MUST be included in all responses; otherwise, the response is malformed.
>
> HTTP/2 does not define a way to carry the version or reason phrase that is included in an HTTP/1.1 status line.